# How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files

Tags: grep, ls

While we use `*` to denote zero or more previous characters in `grep`, we use `*.c` to find all C files when we use it with the `ls` command like `ls *.c`. Could someone tell how the use of `*` differs in these two cases?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Shell file name globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globbing) and [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) use some of the same characters, and they have similar purposes, but you're right, they aren't compatible. File name globbing is a much less powerful system.

In file name globbing:

- `*` means "zero or more characters"
- `?` means "any single character"

But in regexes, you have to use `.*` to mean "zero or more characters", and `.` means "any single character." A `?` means something quite different in regexes: zero or one instance of the preceding RE element.

Square brackets (`[]`) appear to work the same in both systems on the system I'm typing this on, for simple cases at least. This includes things like POSIX character classes (e.g. `[:alpha:]`). That said, if you need your commands to work on many different system types, I recommend against using anything beyond elementary things like lists of characters (e.g. `[abeq]`) and maybe character ranges (e.g. `[a-c]`).

These differences mean the two systems are only directly interchangeable for simple cases. If you need regex matching of file names, you need to do it another way. `find -regex` is one option. (Notice that there is also `find -name`, by the way, which uses glob syntax.)

Comment: I don't know it was called globbing :)

Comment: In addition, there are various flavours of regex. Not all regexes are created the same! And you have many other pattern matching systems, such as SQL _like_, where `'%'` means `'*'`.

Comment: Two major flavors of regexp are POSIX and PCRE (Perl Compatible R.E.).  The later is less long-winded and has some more features. Unix tools and shells generally use POSIX, most programming languages with built-in regexps (except shell) use PCRE.  Just beware the difference when you are reading material on-line.

Answer (score 12):

Answering to the question expressed in the original title:

> ***Why*** do regular expressions differ from that used to filter files?

File name expansion predates regular expressions, already existed with most operating systems (wildcard/joker characters) and is much simpler and intuitive than the latter.

While `*.txt` is easily understandable by casual users, the analogous `.*\.txt` is something more targeted to experienced users/programmers, not to mention `^.*\.txt$` ...

Comment: Another reason for the “why” part: speed. Regular expressions are slower: http://pastebin.com/3iNCgkE3

Comment: `*.txt` doesn't equal `.*\.txt`, it (mostly) equals `.*\.txt$` because there can be nothing after the `.txt` (at least assuming *reasonable* file name globbing). Perhaps even `^.*\.txt$` somewhat depending on usage. Proves your point?