# Meaning of asterisk (*) in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

```
[USERNAME@host ~] echo -e 'prdxxx\ndadxxx' | grep "da*xxx"
prdxxx
dadxxx
[USERNAME@host ~] echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[USERNAME@host ~] dpkg -l | grep -iw bash
ii  bash                                    4.1-2ubuntu3                                    The GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  bash-completion                         1:1.1-3ubuntu2                                  programmable completion for the bash shell
[USERNAME@host ~]
```

Why does `da*xxx` find `prdxxx` too? It doesn't contains `da`... did I found a grep bug? or is this a feature?

Comment: Related to your confusion, see [Why do regular expressions differ from that used to filter files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/why-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-that-used-to-filter-files).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is working fine as per the meaning of the '*'.

`*` -> 0 or more occurences of prev character.

Since you are checking for a*, this will match 0 or more a's. This means `da*xxx`  can match dxxx, daxxx, daaxxx, daaaxxx, and so on.

Comment: why does "da*xxx" finds "prdxxx" string too?

Comment: becuase it contains dxxx.   It does not matter what is before or after that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between normal shell file name patterns (called [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29))  where `*` matches any number of unknown characters,
and [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that are used for example by `grep`, where `*` stands for zero or more occurences of the previous pattern (this is the character `a` in your example).