# Search for and remove files safely

Tags: rm, xargs, locate

I would like to search for all the `nohup.out` in my mounted filesystems, and delete them.

1. There are some directories and files whose filenames contain space, so I think of `xargs -0`.
2. To be safe, I would like to interactively delete them, i.e. be asked if I really want to delete them. So I think of `rm -i` and `xargs -p`
3. I also would like to delete each found file seperately, so I think of `xargs -n 1`.

But the following command doesn't work in the way I hope.

```
locate  -i nohup.out | xargs -0 -n 1 -p rm -i
```

It doesn't prompt each file to be removed and ask for my permission.

I wonder why and what command works as I hope?

By the way my xargs version is xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2. Can it be the reason?

Comment: `locate` is only as good as the db it looks up. If you haven't run `updatedb`  in a while, locate will be near useless. You'll want to use `find`. Additionally, you don't specify *what* doesn't work the way you hope?

Comment: yes, I want to use `locate` after `updatedb`, because it is faster. My command doesn't prompt each file to be removed and ask for my permission

Comment: what's the output look like for you when you run it? I run xargs without passing the `-i` to `rm` and it works just fine.

Comment: AFAIK `locate` doesn't produce null-separated output by default, so you're creating a newline-separated list which `xargs -0` will treat as a single argument, no?

Comment: @steeldriver: you may be right.

Comment: For locate vs find: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60205/locate-vs-find-usage-pros-and-cons-of-each-other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the following command doesn't work in the way I hope.
>
> `locate  -i nohup.out | xargs -0 -n 1 -p rm -i`

Of course if you are using `xargs -0` then you must match that with `locate -0`.

> It doesn't prompt each file to be removed and ask for my permission.
>   I wonder why

`xargs` should read input from `/dev/tty` when prompting you.   It works that way so that there is no conflict between the use of `xargs`'s stdin for reading arguments from `locate` and reading responses for the `-p` option.

However, you are using `xargs` to run `rm -i`.     The `rm -i` command also wants to read your input, which it will read from stdin.   Hence it eats up part of `xargs`'s input and things don't work how you expect.

> and what command works as I hope?

If you are using Bash, this is one option:

```
xargs -a <(locate -0 -i nohup.out) -0 -n 1 -p rm -i
```

However, you can also do everything in find:

```
find / -depth -name nohup.out -ok rm -i '{}' ';'
```

Change ';' to '+' to delete more than one file at a time.  This requirement and the various ways you can solve this problem are explained in [the Texinfo manual for findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Cleaning-Up.html#Cleaning-Up).

Comment: Thanks. Is `-depth` here necessary?

Comment: Strictly, no.   But when removing things, you need to remove containing directories after their contents (else the removing fails).  This means that in general using -depth is best.   Since here we are using "rm" without "-r" we would not be able to remove a directory anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I don't observe the problem that `rm -i` "eats up part of xargs's input and things don't work how you expect."

Comment: You're right, I'd forgotten that I fixed this in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/commit/?id=6c40e5651

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` not `locate`

```
find . -name "nohup.out" | xargs -n 1 -p rm
```

When you add `rm -i` it acts as the input for the `-p` prompt

You can use `find` this way too

```
find . -name "nohup.out" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks. what if use locate instead of find?

Comment: I've never preferred  `locate` for the fact that I have to `updatedb`

Comment: Why is `updatedb` a reason?

Comment: Mostly searching for files not necessarily using only its name, I've security concerns for `locate` addressed here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60208/49374

Answer (score 2):

If you want interactive behaviour and prompting with xargs, you might want to do this instead:

```
locate  -i nohup.out | xargs -d '\n' -L1 -p rm
```

Comment: what if spaces in filenames?

Comment: @Tim updated answer. see edit.

Comment: Thanks. why use `-L1`? Why not `-n 1`?

Comment: Can only one of `xargs -p` and `rm -i` be used, not both? When both, it seems answering `yes` doesn't commit a removal action.

Comment: @Tim, I usually wouldn't expect an interactive command to run through another command that probably starts it as a subshell. Empirically, it tried it and it didn't work, so I'm going to assume both can't be used together, at least not in this way.

Comment: are  -L1 and -n 1 the same?

Comment: No they are not, the man page says `-n` specifies number of args passed to the command and `-L` specifies number of lines to be read from input.

Comment: here each line in the output of `locate` is treated as a argument by `xargs`, so are `-L1` and `-n 1` the same?

Comment: @Tim possibly, that's a subtlety I don't quite understand, you might want to create a fresh question about it.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
find /path/to/mounted_fs -xdev -type f -name nohup.out -exec rm -i {} +
```

`-xdev` limited `find` to search only in your mounted filesystems. Using `-exec rm -i {} +` like you use `xargs` but without issue with special characters in filename.

---

The problem with your command:

```
locate -i nohup.out | xargs -0 -n 1 -p rm -i
```

you told `xargs` to use `\0` as input separator, but `locate` output did not use `\0` but `\n`, so `xargs` would see `locate` output as a big string.