# Are `-L1` and `-n 1` the same for `xargs`?

Tags: xargs

From [Search for and remove files safely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266216/search-for-and-remove-files-safely/266222#266222)

```
locate  -i nohup.out | xargs -d '\n' -L1 -p rm
```

Each line in the output of locate is treated as a argument by xargs, so are `-L1` and `-n 1` the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual:

> -L max-lines
> Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line.  Implies -x.
>
> -n max-args
> Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which  case xargs will exit.
>
> -d delim
> Input items are terminated by the specified character. [...]

Based on this and my understanding, in your case `-L1` and `-n1` are made equivalent both by the argument `1` passed and the delimiter changed from blank space to `\n` (newline) by the argument `-d`

For example, without the `-d` argument if you were to have a blank space in your locate output, then this line would be splitted into two arguments and hence 2 different use of rm with `-n1`, while it would still be treated as one argument and only one command with `-L1`

Comment: re. the last paragraph, without `-d '\n'`, one line with two words results in two args to the command with `-L1`. It's just that with `-L1` it doesn't join args from multiple input lines, it still splits them as usual

Comment: I agree, tho the emphasis was more that with a `foo bar` output from locate, with `-L` you get `rm foo bar`, and with `-n` you would rather get `rm foo` `rm bar`. Which I'll agree have no impact here but might have with a command other than rm.

Comment: Thanks. What does "Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line" mean? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448333/what-does-trailing-blanks-cause-an-input-line-to-be-logically-continued-on-the

Comment: @Lencell, it matters a bunch, if you have filenames with spaces. Well, unless `locate` produces output with quoting compatible with `xargs`, that is. Two arguments `foo` and `bar` is different from one argument `foo bar`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the difference, based on reading the manual, is that `-L` filters for *nonblank* lines, while `-n` does not.  Presuming that `locate` will never output a line containing only whitespace, they should be functionally identical in this use-case.

Answer (score 3):

**`-n` splits on any whitespace, `-L` splits on newlines**

They therefore produce different outcomes:

```
printf '1 2\n3 4\n' | xargs -L1 echo
```

splits by line and therefore is equivalent to:

```
echo 1 2
echo 3 4
```

which outputs:

```
1 2
3 4
```

However:

```
printf '1 2\n3 4\n' | xargs -n1 echo
```

splits on any whitespace, and is therefore equivalent to:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
```

and produces instead:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527004/why-does-xargs-l-yield-the-right-format-while-xargs-n-doesnt

Answer (score 2):

The option -L is an XSI extension and is not required to be present on embedded systems.

The -n option is part of the basic standard and always works.

See the standard as a reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html

Note that some implementation may also switch the behavior for lines that end in spaces while others may concatenate a line ending in space regardless of whether the -L option has been specified.