# What does "Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line" mean?

Tags: xargs

From the manual of `xargs`:

> ```
> -L max-lines
> ```
>
> Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line. **Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically
> continued on the next input line.** Implies -x.

What does "Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line" mean? Can you show it by some examples? Thanks.

Originated from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448294/674

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What the manual is saying is that, trailing spaces at the end of a line of input will cause `xargs` to treat it as though it were part of the following line - effectively escaping the newline. Consider the following command execution:

```
user@host~:$ (echo "line1"; echo "line2") | xargs -L 1 echo
line1
line2
```

Because of the `-L 1` option, each line of input is processed separately, so we get two lines of output. Now compare this with the following example, where the first line of input contains a trailing space:

```
user@host~:$ (echo "line1 "; echo "line2") | xargs -L 1 echo
line1 line2
```

Notice that the two lines are treated as a single line of input by `xargs`.

---

It's also worth noting (per the comments) that the `-L max-lines` option is an XSI extension (cf. [the `xargs` man page on the Open Group website](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html)). This is also referred to as an X/Open System Interfaces Extension - a supplementary specification to the [Single UNIX Specification (SUS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification).

For more information regarding the differences between POSIX, SUS, and XSI, see the following post:

- [Difference between POSIX, Single UNIX Specification, and Open Group Base Specifications?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14368)

Or consult the [section on conformance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap02.html) from the [Base Definitions Volume](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/idx/xbd.html) of the [Open Group Base Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/).

Comment: Note that this feature in xargs is a **XSI extension**.

Comment: @schily Thanks for the comment. I updated my post.