# Is there a way to benchmark the find command (to compare with locate)?

Tags: find, benchmark

Reading the [accetped answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60208) of the question [locate vs find: usage, pros and cons of each other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60205) which tells that `locate`'s main advantage is speed I wanted to do some testing, whether I can benefit from its usage.

My first step was to estimate the speed of `find` tool when providing a comparable service as `locate` (hence only searching filenames, no extras).

I was surprised to see that

```
time find / 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
```

which I assumed iterates over all files (depended on the users permissions), showed

```
real    0m1.231s
user    0m0.353s
sys 0m0.867s
```

a rather quick result.

My question is if the applied command is a way to actually benchmark the speed of `find`?

An aspect of the question I would be interested to have answered would be if there are some sort of buffers in the filesystem, hence in the OS (which is a linux kernel), which would impact the result?

My results where that droping the caches via `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, vastly increased the speed of `find`:

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
$ time (find / 2>/dev/null >/dev/null)
real    0m24.290s
user    0m1.143s
sys 0m8.230s
```

Yet on my linux system subsequent usage of `find` returned to similar to `mlocate` speeds of about 1sec?

Summed up, I am interested to know **a way to benchmark the find command (to compare with locate)**

*Update/Remark*

While the question was motivated by another one comparing `locate` with `find` and I ask about measuring/benchmarking the speed of `find` I am aware that is is highly unlikely that data gathering from the live OS/filesystem (i.e. `find`) , would be faster then a lookup within a database lookup (i.e. `locate`). With the rather good caching behaviour of my operation systems kernel I nonetheless had rather similar execution times for searching via `find` or `locate`.

The question hence boils down to whether it is enough to drop the operation systems (filesystem) caches, to simulate the "actual" time needed for a `find` done at a cold start and furthermore how realistic it would be to assume that those speed enhancing caches persists (not unsimilar to the `updatedb` `locate` database file) for all subsequent `find` calls.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that your benchmark makes no sense at all.  Even on a RAM disk with a minimal installation, it would take more than a second to traverse the full / partition.  I suspect you get permission errors that stop it from doing much.

Comment: @JuliePelletier considering your comment, should I understand that I need another command to benchmark the speed of `find` or that you intent to hint that there is no possible way for such a benchmark? Both would make a good starting point for an answer

Comment: My comment implies that your test is apparently bad and you should redirect the output to a file instead of `/dev/null` to see what's actually going on.  Expect permission errors as I mentioned, which are most likely since you are apparently no logged in as root.

Comment: I don''t know how to measure the speed of both commands, but by using the command `strace`you will be able to see all the function calls of them, maybe it is useful for you. Take a look to the strace man.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I have not considered permission errors to be a problem, but rather a valid part of the benchmark, in which after all ideally everything in `/` is found and piped the output `/dev/null/` as I did not want to cause distortion (i.e. a measuring of output buffer handling performance) when focus should have been the iteration from find. I will take your adivice though and check if permission errors are creating sort of unpredictable results

Answer (score 2):

**On OpenBSD**, the locate database is by default rebuilt once a week by the [`/etc/weekly`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/daily.8) script invoking `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` as user `nobody`.

The [`locate.updatedb`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/locate.updatedb.8) utility is a `/bin/sh` script (`pdksh` on OpenBSD) that more or less runs `find` on the root filesystems.  Anything that `nobody` can access is put into the locate database.

I find it hard to believe that `find /` would be quicker than `locate` on a system where `locate` uses a database of files that has been created through `find /`.

The difference is, of course, that you may find *more files* by running `find` as a user that has further access than the `nobody` user.

**On Linux**, at least on the Ubuntu machine that I have access to at work, the `locate` database seems to be recreated on a daily basis, according to the `locate(8)` manual.  This is done through the `updatedb` utility.

This utility (a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate` on this machine) is a compiled binary belonging to the package `mlocate`.

You can have a look at [the sources of `mlocate`](https://fedorahosted.org/mlocate/wiki/MlocateDownloads) if you wish, but it's basically a C program that traverses the file system.  `mlocate` also tries to avoid traversing bits of the file system that hasn't changed between runs.

Again, I find it hard to believe that querying the `mlocate` database would be slower (under any circumstances) than running `find /`.

At the end of the day, this is why all `locate` tools (that I know about) work against a database.

Comment: on my linux box (4.8.xx build) I found that with caches (as indicated in the question) any subsequent `find` call was surprisingly quick, I did not indent to imply ant believe that `find` could beat `locate`, I was simply surprised that linux kernels caching did such a good job that `find` did not even take twice as long.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace To benchmark `find /`, you would have to clear the cache between runs. I suppose the easiest way to do that would be to reboot.

Comment: In the question I guessed that `sudo bash -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"` would be sufficient. I will test it though first thing next reboot :)