# I can't get grep with regular expressions to work correctly

Tags: grep

```
ssh1% cat temp

sarah

saab

marrrrrrrrra

marrrrrrrtha

ssh1% grep ar*a temp

grep: No match.
```

Shouldn't this be the output?

```
sarah saab marrrrrra
```

I tried using putty and nxclient for Windows 10.

Comment: What is the output of `ls ar*a`?

Comment: No match.  The only files I have in this directory are Jabberwocky, temp and test.  Someone else answered it but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `csh`, which sees the `*` and tries to expand it as a [shell glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and fails. That is, it's `csh` saying "No match" here, not `grep`. Unlike [Bourne family shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145522/what-does-it-mean-to-be-sh-compatible/145524#145524), `csh` won't pass an unexpandable glob pattern on to the command, so you must quote it to get `csh` to release it to `grep`.

I recommend single quotes here since you aren't trying to [interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) a variable into the string:

```
% grep 'ar*a' temp
sarah
saab
marrrrrrrrra
```

Double quotes will also work in this case because your pattern doesn't contain `$`, but I recommend using single quotes here anyway. It's a habit worth cultivating to carefully consider which quotes you use in langauges that let you use them semi-interchangeably, such as shell, Perl, etc. We don't need string interpolation here, so we will choose not to use the quoting style that allows it.

You should quote RE patterns under Bourne family shells, too, by the way. As Mike Wagner hints in his comment above, because regular expressions and glob patterns [use many of the same special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files/57958#57958), you can sometimes write an RE pattern that just *happens* to also match some files, and is thus unexpectedly expanded by the shell.

Comment: `ar*a` matches `saab`.  `*` is zero-or-more.  so `a` followed by zero-or-more `r`s, followed by another `a`.  The OPs expected output is correct, or would be if he properly quoted the regexp to prevent shell glob expansion.  `grep 'ar*a' temp`

Comment: `ssh1% grep ar.*a temp
    grep: No match.` and `ssh1% grep 'ar*a' temp
sarah
saab
marrrrrrrrra
` are my results.  Why does this not work without the quotes?

Comment: @I'manoob: I've edited the answer to explain `No match` from `csh`, which is what's really going on here, not the glob vs RE issue I originally assumed.

Comment: Your pattern says a possibly followed by some number of rs, followed by another a. Is that what you actually mean to find?          Yes this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @I'manoob: Okay, rewrote the answer to cover just the csh issue

Comment: @cas: Removed the RE vs glob stuff from the answer, since OP confirmed that his stated pattern is correct.

Comment: +1. you might want to mention why you recommend single quotes: single quotes are for when you have fixed strings, double-quotes are for when you want to interpolate (include the value of) a variable or variables.  e.g. `'some string'` vs `"$HOME/filename.txt"`