# Using sed to substitute a string containing variable integers

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a text file and want to use sed to replace the following string (including the "s):

```
" rel="lightbox[1846]" title="
```

with

```
#
```

The numbers between `[` and `]` are variable and change.

I want to include the `"` in the substitution.

I've been reading up on wildcards and think `.` will help in some way — different from `*` wildcards I am used to.

Comment: `sed` doesn't do "wildcards", it does regular expressions.  they are very different (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files). Also, it looks like you're trying to parse/edit HTML or XML.  Don't use sed (or any other regex based tool), use an XML or HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -E 's/" rel="lightbox\[[0-9]+\]" title="/#/g' filename
```

Comment: `gnu sed` also knows `-E`

Comment: @don_crissti You're right, `-E` works although strangely it's not listed in my GNU `sed` man page.

Comment: Yeah... I kept meaning to report the fact it's missing from the manual/info page... I'll prolly do it next week.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is indeed the right tool for this job, with its `s` command (the one that's used the most).

Wildcards for file names in the shell, and regular expressions in tools such as `grep` and `sed`, have a different syntax. See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) for a summary of the differences.

In the text to replace, `[` is a regular expression special character; the other characters stand for themselves. Since it's a special character, it needs to be written as `\[` (the backslash makes the next character stand for itself instead of having its special meaning).

A sequence of digits is `[0-9]*`: `[0-9]` means “any digit”, and `*` means “repeat the preceding character or character set 0 or more times”.

Thus:

```
sed 's/" rel="lightbox\[[0-9]]" title="/#/' <old-file >new-file
```

The single quotes make the shell pass everything in between literally to the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sed 's/^" rel=.*title="/#/g' filename
```

This makes use of the `.` and the `*` you referenced in your question to match characters in the middle of the string which can be variable.  Tested and know to achieve the required result you specified.

Although I just used a small sample of text from the beginning and ending of the string, you could be more precise if there was a chance of inadvertently matching an unwanted string.

Answer (score -1):

sed 's/" rel="lightbox[[0-9]+]" title="/#/g' filename

But if you wanna use it in perl , you have to use it like below

`sed 's/" rel="lightbox\[[0-9]+\]" title="/#/g' filename

Comment: 1) What has the second suggestion to do with perl?  2) How is this not a duplicate of [the older, top-voted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275568/90751)?