# How or Why using `.*?` is better than `.*`?

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards

I answered [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1319942/814740) that was something related to kind of Regular expressions used while grepping an output.

The answer I gave was this :

```
 tail -f log | grep "some_string.*some_string"
```

And then, In three comments to my answer [@Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) wrote this :

> `.*` is greedy and might capture more than you want. `.*?` is usually better.

Then this,

> the `?` is a modifier on `*`, making it lazy instead of the greedy default. Assuming PCRE.

I googled for `PCRE`, but couldn't get what's the significance of this in my answer ?

and finally this,

> I should also point out that this is regex (grep doing POSIX regex by default), not a shell glob.

I only know what a Regex is and very basic usage of it in grep command. So, I couldn't get any of those 3 comments and I have these questions in mind :

- What are differences in usage of **`.*?`** vs. **`.*`**?
- Which is better and under what circumstance? Please provide examples.

Also It would be helpful to understand the comments, If anyone could

---

UPDATE: As an answer to question **How are Regex different from Shell Globs ?** [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) provided [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files) in his comment.

NOTE: If needed, Please read [my answer to this question](https://superuser.com/a/1319942/814740) before answering for referring to the context.

Comment: This is two very different questions. The first question is answered by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files while the second question is dependent on the application of the pattern (it can not be said to be "better" under all circumstances).

Comment: You may [edit] this question to be only about the `.*` vs. `.*?` issue.  The "difference between regular expressions and shell globs" question has already been addressed on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Ashok already pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441939/243481) the difference between `.*` and `.*?`, so I'll just provide some additional information.

`grep` (assuming the GNU version) supports 4 ways to match strings:

- Fixed strings, with the `-F` option
- Basic regular expressions (BRE), default
- Extended regular expressions (ERE), with the `-E` option
- Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), with the `-P` option in GNU grep

`grep` uses BRE by default.

BRE and ERE are documented in the [Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) chapter of POSIX and PCRE is documented in its [official website](https://www.pcre.org). Please note that features and syntax may vary between implementations.

It's worth saying that neither BRE nor ERE support *lazyness*:

> The behavior of multiple adjacent duplication symbols ( '+', '*', '?', and intervals) produces undefined results.

So if you want to use that feature, you'll need to use PCRE instead:

```bash
# PCRE greedy
$ grep -P -o 'c.*s' <<< 'can cats eat plants?'
can cats eat plants

# PCRE lazy
$ grep -P -o 'c.*?s' <<< 'can cats eat plants?'
can cats
```

---

> Could you please explain a little about **`.*`** vs **`.*?`** ?

- `.*` is used to match the "longest"<sup>1</sup> pattern possible.
- `.*?` is used to match the "shortest"<sup>1</sup> pattern possible.

In my experience, the most wanted behavior is usually the second one.

For example, let's say we have the following string and we only want to match the html tags<sup>2</sup>, not the content between them:

```html
<title>My webpage title</title>
```

Now compare `.*` vs `.*?`:

```bash
# Greedy
$ grep -P -o '<.*>' <<< '<title>My webpage title</title>'
<title>My webpage title</title>

# Lazy
$ grep -P -o '<.*?>' <<< '<title>My webpage title</title>'
<title>
</title>
```

---

<sup>1. The meaning of "longest" and "shortest" in a regex context is a bit tricky, [as Kusalananda pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441927/how-or-why-using-is-better-than#comment799799_441939). Refer to official documentation for more information.

2. [It's not recommended to parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/9086893). This is just an example for educational purposes, don't use it in production.</sup>

Comment: Could you please explain a little about **`.*`** vs **`.*?`** ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Updated.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose I take a string like:

`can cats eat plants?`

Using the greedy `c.*s` will match the entire string since it starts with `c` and ends with `s`, being a greedy operator it continues to match until the final occurrence of s.

Whereas using the lazy `c.*?s` will only match until the first occurrence of `s` is found, i.e. string `can cats`.

From the above example, you might be able to gather that:

"Greedy" means matching the longest possible string. "Lazy" means matching the shortest possible string. Adding a `?` to a quantifier like `*`, `+`, `?`, or `{n,m}` makes it lazy.

Comment: "Shortest possible" would be `cats`, so it's not enforcing "shortest possible" strictly in that sense.

Comment: @Kusalananda true, not strictly in that sense but "shortest possible" here means between the first occurrence of both c and s.

Answer (score 1):

A string could be matched in several ways (from simple to more complex):

1. As an static string (Assume var='Hello World!'):

   [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)`[ "$var" = "Hello World!" ] && echo yes`
   [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)`echo "$var" | grep -F "Hello"`
   [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)`grep -F "Hello" <<<"$var"`
2. As a glob:

   [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)`echo ./*`  # list **all** files in pwd.
   [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)`case $var in (*Worl*) echo yes;; (*) echo no;; esac`
   [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)`[[ "$var" == *"Worl"* ]] && echo yes`

   There are basic and extended globs. The `case` example use basic globs. The bash `[[` example use extended globs. The first file match could be basic or extended on some shell like setting `extglob` in bash. Both are identical in this case. Grep could not use globs.

   The asterisk in a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) means something different than an asterisk in a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended):

   [glob](/questions/tagged/glob)`* matches any number (including none) of`**any characters**.
   [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)`* matches any number (including none) of the`**preceding element**.
3. As a basic regular expression (BRE):

   [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)`echo "$var" | sed 's/W.*d//'`   # print: Hello !
   [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)`grep -o 'W.*d' <<<"$var"`     # print World !

   There are no BRE in (basic) shells or awk.
4. Extended regular expressions (ERE):

   [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)`[[ "$var" =~ (H.*l) ]]`      # match: Hello Worl
   [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)`echo "$var" | sed -E 's/(d|o)//g'`   # print: Hell Wrl!
   [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)`awk '/W.*d/{print $1}' <<<"$var"`   # print: Hello
   [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)`grep -oE 'H.*l' <<<"$var"`   # print: Hello Worl
5. Perl Compatible Regular Expressions:

   [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)`grep -oP 'H.*?l`   # print: Hel

Only in a PCRE a `*?` has some specific syntax meaning.
It makes the asterisk lazy (ungreedy): [Laziness Instead of Greediness](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
$ grep -oP 'e.*l' <<<"$var"
ello Worl

$ grep -oP 'e.*?l' <<<"$var"
el
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg, there are [greedy, lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301291/9110606), and [docile or possesive](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html). There are also [lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but those do not apply to the asterisk `*`.

There is an alternative to get the same effect as a non-greedy regex:

```
$ grep -o 'e[^o]*o' <<<"$var"
ello
```

The idea is very simple: don't use a dot `.`, negate the next character to match `[^o]`. With a web tag:

```
$ grep -o '<[^>]*>' <<<'<script type="text/javascript">document.write(5 + 6);</script>'
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

The above should completely clarify all @Bob 3 comments. Paraphrasing:

- A .* is a common regex, not a glob.
- Only a regex could be PCRE compatible.
- In PCRE: a ? modify the * quantifier. `.*` is greedy `.*?` is not.

## Questions

- What are differences in usage of .*? vs. .*?

  - A `.*?` is valid only in PCRE syntax.
  - A `.*` is more portable.
  - The same effect as a non-greedy match could be done by replacing the dot with a negated character range: `[^a]*`
- Which is better and under what circumstance? Please provide examples.
  Better? It depends on the goal. There is no better, each is useful for different purposes. I have provided several examples above. Do you need more?