# Remove data in between 2 words

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I want to remove all data no matter what it is in between 2 words. The two words are `user` and `Gecko)` , exactly as it appears.

For example:


`abcd: efgh user jfslkdj ajskdlfj askldjf Gecko) print`

`ijkl: mnop user fjskdf sdfjkdf skdjf sdkfj Gecko) second`

Should apprear as: 
`abcd: efgh print`

`ijkl: mnop second`

Please let me know if this is possible.

So far, this is what I tried and I know I am far off:

`sed 's/user*Gecko)//g'`

Comment: You may find the discussion here helpful: [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57958/65304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your command like:

```
sed 's/user.*Gecko)//g'
```

It will remove the substring `user.....Gecko)`.

You can use:

```
sed -Ee "s/(.*)(user.*Gecko\))(.*)/\1\3/g" filename
```

It will just print first and third field and will neglect second field which contains everything between user and Gecko) including both.

If you are sure that `user` is not starting word and `Gecko)` is not last word, then you can use:

```
sed -Ee "s/(.*) (user.*Gecko\)) (.*)/\1 \3/g" filename
```

this one is more accurate as it will only replace words separated by space.

Comment: The `g` is not needed at the end of the `s` command as there can't be more than one match per line.  If the line is `XXX user YYY Gecko) XXX user YYY Gecko)` then the pattern would match from the first `user` to the last `Gecko)`.

Comment: And of course you don't need to capture the second field if you are not going to use it, so `sed -Ee 's/(.*) user.*Gecko\) (.*)/\1 \2/' filename`. Note if there is more than one `user` in the line before the `Gecko)` then this approach will remove from the last `user`, whilst the `s/user.*Gekco)//` will remove from the first one.

Comment: Worked like a charm, you got the best answer for that one, thanks. I have another question. Say some lines say `Chrome XXXX` and other lines say `Chrome XXXX OpenFin XXXX`. How do I remove the `Chrome XXXX` only on the lines that has it with `OpenFin XXXX` so that `OpenFin XXXX` can display by itself?

Comment: @IbrahimA `sed -Ee '/OpenFin XXXX/s/Chrome.*?XXXX//'`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below command and it worked fine

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$NF}'  filename
```

output

```
abcd: efgh print
ijkl: mnop second
```