# How to grep for a particular string?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to get a string that matches the following pattern: starts with `foo` and finishes with `bar`.

```
grep -e "^foo*bar$"
```

Comment: `o*` will only match zero or more `o` characters - see [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57958/65304)

Comment: Thanks, I did the following: `grep -e "^foo" -e "bar$" file`. This variant works.

Comment: But you missed the point!

Comment: Maybe, if you want to tell me what is the point that I missed. I actually got the result I expected.

Comment: Well the point is actually a dot. A wild guess? Should I tell it before?

Comment: Use `^foo.*bar$`. That's the point, with intenional pun.

Comment: Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Comment: can anyone tell me why this question is being downvoted?

Comment: @Bionix1441 also note that double quotes are interpreted by shells like `bash` before it is passed to `grep`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 5):

There are three parts to the pattern you want to match:

- The first one is to start the string with 'foo'. So, use a start anchor: '^foo'.
- The second one is to end the string with 'bar'. Here, use an end anchor: 'bar$'.
- The third part is what comes in between the start and end anchors. In your case, you want to match all of the characters zero or more times (i.e. there may or may not be characters in between). This is represented by the expression '.*'. The dot matches any character, and the asterisk quantifier specifies that it may be matched zero or more times.

Putting all of this together, you'll get the expression:

```
grep '^foo.*bar$' file
```

As an example, consider this test file:

```
$ cat testfile
foobar
foo bar
foo 123 bar
123 foo bar
foo bar 123
123 foo bar 123
```

Now running the `grep` command:

```
$ grep '^foo.*bar$' testfile
foobar
foo bar
foo 123 bar
```

Note that the variant you have specified in the comments (`grep -e "^foo" -e "bar$" file`) behaves differently:

```
$ grep -e "^foo" -e "bar$" testfile
foobar
foo bar
foo 123 bar
123 foo bar
foo bar 123
```

This is because the `-e` options are combined with an OR operation. In addition to the original `^foo.*bar$` results, you will also get results matching `^foo` as well as results matching `bar$`.

Comment: I missed this (or) point too.