# Why does the wildcard work differently when placed at the start or at the end of a grep phrase?

Tags: grep

For example, I wanted to count how many files in my current directory have a certain extension.

I used:

```
ls | grep ".txt" | wc -l
```

This works and so does:

```
ls | grep ".txt*" | wc -l
```

But why does this not work either?

```
ls | grep "*.txt" | wc -l
```

Why does the wildcard seem to not work in the grep expression when I use it before the extension and why does it have no effect at the end (all txt files simply end with .txt so I am guessing it does not work if it was something like .txt.zip)?

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions, not wildcards - see for example [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files)

Comment: Yes it does! How do I accept this as the answer? Thank you for the help!

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425), [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ls *.txt
```

This command will use shell globbing to list all files whose names end with `.txt`.

```
$ ls | grep "*.txt"
```

This command will list all (non-hidden) files in the present working directory, and send that output to `grep`, which will match the filenames against the regular expression `/*.txt/`.

```
/*.txt/
```

This regular expression may (depending on what flavor of regular expressions is in play) match a pattern of:

```
*    -- zero or more characters of any type (or possibly only a literal '*'), followed by
.    -- exactly one character of any type, followed by 
txt  -- the literal string 'txt', followed by anything
```

In regular expressions, `*` is a wildcard standing for "zero or more of the preceding subexpression"; but it works differently from shell glob wildcards.  Relatedly, `.` is not a period; it is a wildcard for one character (analogous to the `?` wildcard in shell globs).  As such, this expression would (again, depending on what flavor of regex) match any of `file.txt`, `sometxtfile`, `photo_of_a_txt_file.png`, but indeed not `txtfile` (as there is no match for the one character before `txt`). It is important to know that the literal string `txt` can, therefore, appear anywhere but at the very start of the file name with this regular expression.

A better regular expression to catch file names that end in `.txt` would be `/\.txt$/`:

```
\.  -- A literal .
txt -- The literal string 'txt'
$   -- End of input
```

So therefore, if you insist on piping `ls` into `grep` (and let's not, for the moment, get into the books that could be written on why parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea), you probably mean to do this:

```
$ ls | grep "\.txt$"
```

As for then using `wc`, you don't need to do this.  `grep` can count:

```
$ ls | grep -c "\.txt$"
```

Comment: `/*.txt/` -- "this expression would match any of file.txt, sometxtfile..." -- no, the leading asterisk in the expression is not special (as far as I can read the spec, and as far as my `sed`s and `grep`s work), so the expression would match a string containing an asterisk, then any character, then `txt`, e.g. `a*btxtc` etc. Except if you're using Perl, where an asterisk following nothing would be an error.

Comment: To complicate matters, a *leading* `*` is treated differently in BRE `grep` and ERE `grep -E` (at least in the GNU implementations); in BRE it is treated as literal (which is why the OP sees no output in that case), whereas in ERE it appears to mean zero or more instances of the empty pattern, which matches anything.

Comment: "Regular Expression" is often a misnomer, what with BRE, ERE, PCRE, RRE, JSRE, and all the other flavors out there making them highly irregular.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, I don't think the ["regular"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) there refers to _that_.

Comment: I am aware, @ilkkachu, I was just making light of the term.

Comment: @steeldriver But in posix [an initial * is undefined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03) **the following uses produce undefined results: If these characters appear first in an ERE.** And, in GNU grep, an initial * will match only empty spaces, not any character. Try `echo hello | grep -Eo '*'`, no output, no match (without the o there will be (an empty) match).