# GNU grep & find -regex: Why is . needed in the regex and why can't i use POSIX character classes?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I was **trying to find files in a certain directory which don't adhere to the naming guidelines for UNIX-like systems**.

When using with find the command `find <dir> -regex '.*[^-_./0-9a-zA-Z].*'` **returns the files of interest**.

my question with above command line is:

1. Why did we need the **any one character** metacharacter `.` before the **zero or more** `*` metacharacter at the start and end of the regex respectively for this to work as intended. when i initially tried with `find <dir> -regex '*[^-_./0-9a-zA-Z]*'` that returned nothing.
2. Furthermore, if I replace the `character ranges` in the regex with their corresponding `POSIX character classes` with everything else intact: `find <dir> -regex '.*[^-_./[:digit:][:lower:][:upper:]].*'` it returns nothing. why is it this way?

TIA!

Comment: Have you read the description of `-regex`? It matches over the whole path.

Comment: and what about that?

Comment: If you exclude `/`, the path separator, in what system do you think your regex will match a whole path?

Comment: @muru Where am I excluding the path separator? the regex doesn't exclude the path separator, It is supposed to find files which have characters **other than the recommended characters:** - or _ or . or / or digits or lowercase letters or uppercase letters... So, to answer you question I think this will work on **all** UNIX-like systems. Besides, that wasn't my question?!

Comment: If you don't include `.` which matches anything, and explicitly exclude `/`, which is the path separator, of course you're excluding the path separator. I have no idea what your random bolding is meant to imply.

Comment: @muru if i don't include `.` and don't explicitly exclude the `/`, the resulting regex `*[^-_.0-9a-zA-Z]*` won't work then either, will it? `.` has to be included not just because of the path separator. My misconception here was cleared pretty nicely by @steeldriver. The regex won't work without the leading and trailing `.` because then the quantifier `*`  isn't specifying what it wants to have none or more of. It was a misconception because I was mixing up the shell wildcard `*` with the regex quantifier `*`...

Comment: ...which @steeldriver intuited out pretty well.  You on the other hand, just kept nitpicking on one thing that was not relevant to my question, IMO. So, apologies if you found my **random bolding** off-putting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files)

Comment: @muru, the command looks for filenames that contain anything other _but_ the listed characters. Like, say, a comma, or a dollar sign or ... If  the slash wasn't listed, it would match pretty much everything (since `-regex` matches against the full path)

Comment: I suppose the alternative would be `find . ! -regex '[-_./0-9a-zA-Z]*'`, if that's any clearer

Comment: @muru yes, it does answer the first question. steeldriver has answered both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `*` in regular expression syntax is a *quantifier* applying to the previous regex atom (in this case, `.`). It is **not** itself a "zero or more metacharacter" as it would be in shell pattern matching syntax (aka "globbing").
2. may be an idiocyncracy of the default Emacs regextype - try `-regextype posix-basic` or `-regextype egrep` for example if you want more familiar behavior.

Comment: I think they want to find filenames that contain "unwanted" characters, any one not listed there. In which case `/` should indeed be in the list.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks - I really shouldn't post before coffee

Comment: This is what I was missing, the distinction between `*` in shell wildcards and POSIX REs. Thanks @steeldriver.