# Renaming with wildcard

Tags: command-line, rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files, using the rename command, from

```
Blue - This file is called Blue ok.txt
Red - This file is called Red ok.txt
Orange and Yellow - This file is called Orange and Yellow ok.txt
```

... into:

```
Blue.txt
Red.txt
Orange and Yellow.txt
```

I'm having trouble getting it to understand the wildcard in the middle. I've tried:

```
rename -f 's/ - This file is called* ok//gi' *.txt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: ... also [How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files)

Comment: @steeldriver, yep, that's a better one, thanks.

Comment: @ilkkachu for some reason it wouldn't let me suggest it as a duplicate (the button was grayed out)

Comment: Read the linked answers, but in short: the `d* ok` in your regex means zero-or-more `d` characters followed by " ok".  You want `d.* ok`, which means `d` followed by zero-or-more of **any** character, followed by " ok".